# importing pycurl to crossbar.io errors out

Tags: python, import, pypy, pycurl, crossbar

OK so I want to use crossbar.io and build an app in python.

I can get the demo working however my app will need to spin off threads which use pycurl to listen to long-lived http connects.

separately, the crossbar.io code and the pycurl code work, however when i do the following i get "import not found":

```
import sys
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.logger import Logger

from autobahn.twisted.util import sleep
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession
from autobahn.wamp.exception import ApplicationError

from legacy_misc import Legacy_Listener

client = Legacy_Listener("box01")
client.daemon = True
client.start()

class AppSession(ApplicationSession):

log = Logger()
@inlineCallbacks
def onJoin(self, details):

    # SUBSCRIBE to a topic and receive events
    #
    def onhello(msg):
        self.log.info("event for 'onhello' received: {msg}", msg=msg)

    yield self.subscribe(onhello, 'com.example.onhello')
    self.log.info("subscribed to topic 'onhello'")

    # REGISTER a procedure for remote calling
    #
    def add2(x, y):
        self.log.info("add2() called with {x} and {y}", x=x, y=y)
        return x + y

    yield self.register(add2, 'com.example.add2')
    self.log.info("procedure add2() registered")

    # PUBLISH and CALL every second .. forever
    #
    counter = 0
    while True:

        # PUBLISH an event
        #
        yield self.publish('com.example.oncounter', counter)
        self.log.info("published to 'oncounter' with counter {counter}",
                        counter=counter)
        counter += 1

        if counter > 5:
            break

        # CALL a remote procedure
        #
        try:
            res = yield self.call('com.example.mul2', counter, 3)
            self.log.info("mult() called with result: {result}",
                            result=res)
        except ApplicationError as e:
            # ignore errors due to the frontend not yet having
            # registered the procedure we would like to call
            if e.error != 'wamp.error.no_such_procedure':
                raise e

        yield sleep(1)
```

The legacy_Listener contains the thread code with a "import pycurl" (this module works great by itself)

Now once i mix the crossbar.io example code with my own code, i get the following error:

```
2016-04-09T20:42:09+0100 [Container   26333] Worker process starting (PyPy-EPollReactor) ..
```

2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Controller  26219] Container with ID 'worker2' and PID 26333 started
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333] Component loading failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/websocket.py", line 90, in onMessage
    self._session.onMessage(msg)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py", line 809, in onMessage
    on_reply = txaio.as_future(endpoint.fn, *invoke_args, **invoke_kwargs)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/txaio/tx.py", line 339, in as_future
    return maybeDeferred(fun, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
---  ---
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker/container.py", line 192, in start_container_component
    create_component = _appsession_loader(config)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker/**init**.py", line 74, in _appsession_loader
    pythonpath=sys.path
autobahn.wamp.exception.ApplicationError: ApplicationError(error=, args=['Failed to import class \'hello.AppSession\'\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py", line 809, in onMessage\n    on_reply = txaio.as_future(endpoint.fn, *invoke_args, **invoke_kwargs)\n  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/txaio/tx.py", line 339, in as_future\n    return maybeDeferred(fun, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred\n    result = f(*args, **kw)\n  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker/container.py", line 192, in start_container_component\n    create_component = _appsession_loader(config)\n---  ---\n  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker/**init**.py", line 58, in _appsession_loader\n    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)\n  File "/opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module\n    **import**(name)\n  File "/home/osboxes/qbtwebmon/hello.py", line 36, in \n    from legacy_misc import Legacy_Listener\nexceptions.ImportError: No module named legacy_misc\n'], kwargs={'pythonpath': [u'/home/osboxes/qbtwebmon', '/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker', '/opt/crossbar/bin', '/opt/crossbar/lib_pypy/**extensions**', '/opt/crossbar/lib_pypy', '/opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7', '/opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/plat-linux2', '/opt/crossbar/site-packages', '/home/osboxes/qbtwebmon/wamp_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']}, enc_algo=None)

2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]   Python module search paths:
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /home/osboxes/qbtwebmon
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/bin
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/lib_pypy/**extensions**
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/lib_pypy
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/plat-linux2
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /opt/crossbar/site-packages
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333]     /home/osboxes/qbtwebmon/wamp_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Container   26333] NativeWorkerSession.onUserError
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Controller  26219] crossbar.error.class_import_failed: Failed to import class 'hello.AppSession'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py", line 809, in onMessage
    on_reply = txaio.as_future(endpoint.fn, *invoke_args, **invoke_kwargs)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/txaio/tx.py", line 339, in as_future
    return maybeDeferred(fun, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker/container.py", line 192, in start_container_component
    create_component = _appsession_loader(config)
---  ---
  File "/opt/crossbar/site-packages/crossbar/worker/**init**.py", line 58, in _appsession_loader
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
    **import**(name)
  File "/home/osboxes/qbtwebmon/hello.py", line 36, in 
    from legacy_misc import Legacy_Listener
exceptions.ImportError: No module named legacy_misc

2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Controller  26219] sending TERM to subprocess 26272
2016-04-09T20:42:13+0100 [Controller  26219] waiting for 26272 to exit...

Now after hours of googling, I have realised that pycurl does not work in pypy, which is what crossbar.io is running, but i was wondering if there is a way to say "use pypy" for running crossbar and "use cpython" for running the project?

finally, this isnt a path issue, i have appended it and tested it for that.

Answer (score 0):

OK fixed, basically i used the "yum install crossbar" method to install which is written in pypy. If you install via pip it gives you the CPython version which is also faster than the pypy version IMHO.

Note: pip install crossbar[all] is a pain, you fix one compilation issue then theres another one, just do the standard pip install crossbar instead.